# Uses of a stack in a Java application

Tags: java, stack

I have a task given to me to implement stacks in a java application that uses the following member methods:

```
pop();
push();
peek();
empty();
search();
```

I have to use all of the above mentioned methods.
I'm asking help on what application I can do this requirement in using stacks.
I was thinking something in the lines of black Jack since one the deck is shuffled the dealer will only give out cards from the top of the deck.. 
Can some help think of another idea.

Note: I am asking for an idea of an application using the above mentioned requirements note the code itself, I will code the program myself

Comment: So what have you done?

Comment: @pedromss He's not asking for help, he's asking for inspiration. Either way, it's off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @pedromss atleast he's not asking for code...

Comment: try to implement [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). It is a very good exercise with a stack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge number of uses for stacks. Path finding, AI, menu navigation, card games as you said, etc. Your program itself uses a stack to execute function calls.

Many recursive functions can be rewritten using a stack to reduce memory consumption.  I'd start there if you just want experience with stacks.  Find a good recursive algorithm, try to rewrite it using a stack.